# how to decide which distribution has the following variable

Tags: probability

David choose digits one by one, So that each digit from $\{0,\ldots,9\}$ has the same probability 
to be choosen, and in each time the selection is independent.

let $X$ be the number of times that $0$ occurs between the first two ocurrences of $9$. (for example for the seq $13904509\ldots$, $X=2$)

what is the distribution of the $X$?

$1.$ Same as $Y-1$, when $Y$ is a geometric variable.

$2.$ Poisson

$3.$ Uniform

$4.$ None of the above

I eliminated uniform, because $X$ isn't bounded
I don't think it is option 1, because option 1 fit to the question about how many digits in general occur between the to occurrences of $9$.

can someone help me from here? I will be happy get any sort of time about how to solve this kind of questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Imagine you are watching the tosses as they occur. Call a $0$ a failure, and the second $9$ a success. So we are looking at the number of failures until the first success.

Comment: but in this way X will be a variable that counts the number of digits that occure bewtween the first "9" and the second "9" (?) and I am looking for the number of "0" between the two "9"

Comment: We are not interested in any digits other than $0$ or $9$. So a toss that results in one of those can be treated as a non-toss. Thus the problem is equivalent to counting the number of tails **before** the first head, when tossing a fair coin.

Comment: thanks, it's a new perspective for me. in this case what will be the parameter of Y? 0.5?

Comment: Yes, it is $1/2$. As for the perspective, let's look at a simpler problem where the idea will be clear. Toss a fair die repeatedly. What is the probability you will get a $1$ before you get a $6$? Slightly fancier: what is the probability you will get a $1$ or a $2$ before you get a $6$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n\geqslant0$, knowing that $X\geqslant n$, $X\geqslant n+1$ happens when one meets a (new) $0$ before meeting another $9$. Since $0$ and $9$ are equiprobable, this happens with probability $p=\frac12$. Hence, for every $n\geqslant0$, $P[X\geqslant n+1\mid X\geqslant n]=p$.

Can you recognize the distribution of $X$ from this computation?

Hints:

- For every $n\geqslant0$, $P[X\geqslant n+1]=P[X\geqslant n+1\mid X\geqslant n]\cdot P[X\geqslant n]$.
- For every $n\geqslant0$, $P[X=n]=P[X\geqslant n+1]-P[X\geqslant n]$.